# How can I start over in Battle Islands on PSN?

Tags: psn, battle-islands

I made some poor resource-allocation choices during my first couple of campaigns in Battle Islands on the PS4. I'd like to start over from scratch, so that I can use my initial set of resources in a more strategically-sound way. However, the game doesn't seem to have a quit or reset option, and a search of [the wiki](http://battleislands.wikia.com) didn't turn up anything that seemed applicable to the PSN versions of the game.

How can I reset the PSN version of the game to its initial state?

Answer (score 1):

Just go on your PS4 settings and find the saved data folder. Then delete the Battle Island File form there.